# Using process in c# to run multiple matlab scripts

Tags: c#, matlab, process

So I have a matlab script which initializes some values and then I want to run another matlab script. Is there any way I could tell my process to run another script after the first one.

Here's my code, which works fine but only runs one script.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"matlab.exe", @"-r script1");
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = info;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;              
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
evHandledGetLatest = process.HasExited;
```

How can I after script1 run script2?
I want to run script1 and script2 in the same process, script2 needs to have values (in matlab workspace) created by script1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd strongly consider calling the Matlab script directly from C#. This approach will allow you to get the results from script1 and pass them to script2.

You'll need to add a reference to the Matlab COM object.

For full details see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html